# iptables-restore failing: "The -t option ... cannot be used"

Tags: debian, iptables

I have a very simple set of iptables rules:

```
*filter

-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT

-A INPUT -mstate --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -ptcp -mstate --state NEW --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: " --log-level 7

-A INPUT -j DROP
-A FORWARD -j DROP

COMMIT
```

... but am getting a confusing error:

```
iptables-restore v1.8.2 (nf_tables): The -t option (seen in line 8) cannot be used in iptables-restore.

Error occurred at line: 8
```

As can be seen, the -t option is not invoked on line 8--or any other line, for the matter. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

```
-mstate
-ptcp
```

Apparently the option parser in `iptables-restore` isn't exactly the same as the getopt() parser used for command-line parameters, and doesn't know the difference between options with arguments and options without. So it interprets the word as `-m -s -t -a -t -e`, as if it consisted entirely of bundled no-arg options.